# How to get Width of Button in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I want to resize the width of My button from Kotlin code.

I tried this

```
 private var viewPagerPageChangeListener: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener = object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        addBottomDots(position)
        if (position == layouts!!.size - 1) {
            btnNext!!.text = getString(R.string.start)
            btnNext!!.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(315, 44) 
            btnSkip!!.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            btnNext!!.text = getString(R.string.next)
            btnSkip!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

I am using this in the View Pager.

After running my application, button is disappeared from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View's **scaleX** and **scaleY** if you just want to simply stretch the view. Getting the actual width and height is a bit complicated as you have to take into account listening to a ViewTreeObserver